# Convert XML to CSV with xmlstarlet using double quotes on value

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

This shows how to convert xml to CSV

http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/transforming-xml-document-into-csv-using-xmlstarlet/

```
xmlstarlet \
  sel -T -t -m /root/record \
  -v "concat(@id,';',object/keyF,';',object/keyG)" \
  -n test.xml
```

However, some of my values have have commas in the value.  How do I get my CSV to parse correctly?  Is there a way to add double quotes to the KeyF value?  If so, what would be the syntax?

Example

```
  <keyF>val_1F</keyF>
```

object/keyF will return val_1F, but I need "val_1F"

Answer (score 3):

You simply add the `"` along with the `;`, the only extra complication is that `"` needs to be escaped so the shell doesn't interpret it:

```
xmlstarlet \
  sel -T -t -m /root/record \
  -v "concat('\"', @id,'\";\"',object/keyF,'\";\"',object/keyG, '\"')" \
  -n test.xml
```

Comment: What if some values contain quote character?

Comment: @Vanuan use something like `str:replace(object/may-have-quotes, '\"', '\\\"')` to escape the quotes with backslash.

Comment: How to do it with revers need: to put in single quot?

Comment: @schweik `"concat(\"'\", @id, \"';'\",...`